# Importing sql-files larger than 2GB?

Tags: mysql, import, large-files

I've got an SQL file that is about 3GB. I can't seem to find any good solution for importing this sql into mysql. I've tried handling import from a specified folder in the phpmyadmin-environment, but that gave me a timeout after 5h (No I didn't wait ;-))

I've tried bigdump, but it has a restriction of 2GB, tried Editor 010 (http://www.sweetscape.com/) so I could split the file, but even then a specific insert-statment was so many rows that was over 1GB and that didn't do the trick.

It seems that 2GB is a filesystem-issue together with `fseek()`

Of couse I could split it row for row and manually change things, but that would really be a last resort.

I'm using Windows and WAMP.

Any ideas?

Comment: PHPmyAdmin will timeout, you need to connect directly. I use a Mac, however, and when I have this kind of problem I use a desktop app (like Sequel Pro) and connect directly to the database. You could also use mysql monitor to connect directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes you don't see the obvious. In case anyone stumple upon this issue:

It was just matter of using the old fashioned command line...

```
mysql -u <user> -p<password> <database> < databas.sql
```

Comment: Exactly what I was about to write.